# What is the best way to store large amounts of data in an array?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, database

I have a database of 100,000 contacts.

I have a multiple select box which I would like to use to select contacts to add to a specific mailing list.

My problem is that I am currently storing the data for the mailing list in a serialized array format (PHP) in MySQL.

When I select over a certain number of contacts, something seems to break (I assume not enough memory) and does not update the array.

Is there a best way to store a large array in MySQL and is there a best way to keep memory usage in a PHP `array()` low?

**Code Example**

```
if(isset($_POST['add'])) {
    $name = $core->EscapeString($_POST['name']);
    $desc = $core->EscapeString($_POST['desc']);
    foreach($_POST['addSelect'] as $null => $id) {
        if(!in_array($id, $recipientArray)) {
            $recipientArray[] = $id;
        }
    }
    $contacts->updateML($lid, $name, $desc, serialize($recipientArray));
}
else if(isset($_POST['rm'])) {
    $name = $core->EscapeString($_POST['name']);
    $desc = $core->EscapeString($_POST['desc']);
    foreach($recipientArray as $null => $id) {
        foreach($_POST['rmSelect'] as $null1 => $id1) {
            if($id == $id1) {
                unset($recipientArray[$null]);
            }
        }
    }
    $contacts->updateML($lid, $name, $desc, serialize($recipientArray));
}
```

**UpdateML Function**

```
//Class 3, Function 16
function updateML($lid = '', $name = '', $desc = '', $recip = '') {
    global $MySQLi;
    $query = "UPDATE `mailing_lists` SET `name` = '".$name."', `desc` = '".$desc."', `recipients` = '".$recip."' WHERE `list_id` = '".$lid."' LIMIT 1";
    $commit = $MySQLi->query($query);
    if($commit == false) {
        die("Issues with the database were detected. Please email peter@domain.com quoting error code: <strong>CLASS3/16.1</strong>.");
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: 100,000 records is *not* "big data"

Comment: Fair point. Worded it incorrectly. - Edited.

Comment: If you're serializing data into MySQL, you're probably doing it wrong.

Comment: what are all the kinds of operations you are doing with the data?

Comment: You can use `SplFixedArray` to get a lower memory footprint. However, if you use a relational database then it makes no sense to save serialized data in there. You're turning a Ferrari into a Trabant that way, it just becomes a glorified text file. The real solution to your problem is normalizing your data. All other attempts to stick all that info into an array will result in a failure at some point, due to lack of memory or something else.

Comment: Being honest, I'm not a guru at PHP and so all *helpful* comments are really welcomed. The main reason of storing it there is I store an array of contact ID's to use later on in the mailing process. Do you think storing it maybe comma separated may be preferred?

Comment: the best way as @N.B. mentioned is to normalize your data and your database. so keep each `id` in one separate record. do not be afraid of that your table will grow very big. having millions of records in a `mysql` database is nothing. it can be handled very easily.

Comment: I think your approach is wrong though. I would consider using ajax method for that dropdown. Loading 10000+ rows in a dropdown is rather excessive. Ajax dropdowns can include "smart loading" which add data while people scroll and do auto completion when someone starts typing in your dropdown. Google "ajax dropdown" or the likes for examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need 2 tables. One for Mailing List Definition, one for recipients. In recipients table you'd need to have a foreign key relating the record to appropriate mailing list.

so mailing_lists table looks like this:

```
ml_id
name
desc
```

and recipients looks like this:

```
r_id
email
ml_id
```

First add the mailing list to the database:

```
INSERT INTO mailing_lists SET name = 'my first list', desc = 'mailsareus'
```

When you add new recipients just add a new row to recipients table:

```
INSERT INTO recipients SET email = 'xxx@mail.com', ml_id = 1
```

If you need to get all the recipients and definition from a mailing list just use a join

```
SELECT * FROM mailing_lists JOIN recipients ON recipients.ml_id = mailing_lists.ml_id
```